# Custom pluralization in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a month range string, and want to pluralize it that way:

`I18n.t :range, min: min_date, max: max_date`

If `min_date` and `max_date` are equal, it should translate to `%{min_date} to %{max_date}`, but if they are different I want to show just `%{min_date}`.

How can I do it having just this at my locale file:

`range:
  one: "%{min_date}"
  other: "%{min_date} to %{max_date}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a job for the i18n interpolation. You are probably much better of to just use a method (e.g. in a helper module). That way, you are being explicit about what you want to achieve and don't need to abuse unrelated mechanisms.

```
def render_range(min_date, max_date)
  if min_date == max_date
    min_date.to_s
  else
    I18n.t :range, min: min_date.to_s, max: max_date.to_s
  end
end
```

Then, in your locate file, you can specify the range key like this:

```
range: "%{min} to %{max}"
```